# Criterion for a basis of a topology

Tags: general-topology

Here is part of Munkres' book on topology:[image]

I suppose the reader is supposed to use

[image]

to prove this. But I don't understand how. The lemma says that if there is a space with a *fixed* topology, then to show that a set forms a basis, one has to take an open set from the fixed topology and do something. But the order topology is being defined, how can I take an open set and prove that it contains a basis element if I don't know what open sets are yet?

Comment: To step back a bit, one has a fixed topology when all the open sets are known (or, equivalently, when all of its *closed* sets are known).  In that context we can ask whether a certain subset of the open sets do or do not constitute a *basis* for the topology.  That's where the Lemma you cite might come into play.  Given that framework, what is *your* Question?  Merely quoting from the Munkres textbook does not fully state a problem to be solved.

Comment: My question is in the last sentence, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirements for $\mathcal{B}\subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ to be a base for some topology on $X$ are (second edition., paragraph 13, page 78):

(1) $\bigcup \mathcal{B} = X$, or equivalently for every $x \in X$ there is some $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$.

(2) For all $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$, for all $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$: there exists some $B_3 \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B_3 \subseteq B_1 \cap B_2$.

The lemma 13.2 is not used here: this is to characterise a base for an already given topology, while in the case at hand we want to define a topology by a suitable base.

Munkres suggests to check condition (2) by checking that the set of intervals he describes ($\mathcal{B}$) has the property that if $B_1 , B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ we either have $B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ again (so we can take $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$) or $\emptyset$ (in which case the condition is voidly true as there are no $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ to check.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathscr B$ doesn't define a topology on $X$.  You need to take arbitrary unions and finite intersections of elements of $\mathscr B$ to fulfill the definition of a topology.

$\mathscr B$ is a basis for the topology it *generates*...

Actually,  $\mathscr B$ is closed under finite intersections, as Munkres notes.

But you need to throw in arbitrary unions...  $\mathscr B$ isn't closed under arbitrary unions.

Thus $\mathscr B$ generates a topology on $X$.

Comment: Munkres highlights a couple of things to check to be sure $\mathscr B$ actually serves as a basis.  Since the entire set $X$ must be open, every element $x\in X$ has to belong to some set in $\mathscr B$.  Munkres further asks the reader to check $\mathscr B$ is closed under finite intersections, as you noted.  I don't have my copy of Munkres handy, but it seems likely that a different Lemma than the one the OP has identified was intended to be used.

Comment: Perhaps...  I lost my copy of Munkres years ago.  I remember it was red...

Comment: @hardmath there are useful criteria on wolfram and Wikipedia...

Comment: @hardmath You are right, I think I should use just the definition instead of the lemma. (The definition can be found in my previous question.) But it looks like the definition is obviously satisfied, so now I'm confused why Munkres says to consider a few cases and verify something, if everything looks too trivial (or I misunderstand something).

Comment: Now I see. Not all cases are trivial. If we take $(a,b]$ and $[b,c)$, then the intersection will be a singleton. It will not contain a basis element. So it cannot be a basis, according to the definition... I must be missing something.

Comment: @user531587:  Note all "half-open" intervals are allowed in the order topology.  In particular the two sets you give are admitted only if $b$ is both a greatest element and a least element, in which case the intersection being a singleton is correct and desirable.